# input type date não é preenchido

Tags: html5, datepicker

Eu preencho um campo DateTime com `input type="date"` e consigo gravá-lo no banco de dados normalmente.

Quando recupero o registro do banco e tento exibi-lo com o mesmo tipo de input, ele me mostra o campo preenchido com `01/01/0001`. Se examino o código fonte da página, verifico que a data recuperada está lá, conforme foi gravada no banco, mas no formato `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Sei que o `input type=date` precisa receber a data no formato `yyyy-MM-dd` mas não sei como fazer isso. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Qual a linguagem server-side que você está utilizando? PHP, MVC C#?

Comment: Transforme a data de `dd/MM/yyyy` para `yyyy-MM-dd` antes de setar o value.

Comment: @Beterraba acho que é isso que o autor quer ajuda ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. Ele perguntou o que estava fazendo de errado. Não colocar a data no formato certo é o que ele está fazendo de errado :D!

Comment: Acho que isso tem haver com a configuração do browser ou do próprio micro.

Comment: Estou usando MVC4 com c#. Os valores dos campos do banco são transferidos para as propriedades da classe pelo Model Binder. Não sei como mudar o comportamento do Model Binder para que ele formate a data no formato esperado pelo datepicker (yyyy-MM-dd) e não gostaria de fazer isso na marra.

Answer (score 2):

Pegue o dado e transforme assim na sua View:

***View***

```
<input type="date" value="@SeuModelo.CampoData.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />
```

Troque 'SeuModelo.CampoData' pelo respectivo do seu modelo, lembrando que ele deve ser do tipo `DateTime`, você também pode testar com esse:

```
<input type="date" value="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />
```

Comment: Funcionou Diego! O único porém é que estou usando @Html.EditorFor(p => p.DataNascimento, new { value=@Model.DataNascimento.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") }) e, com esta abordagem, não funciona. Eu gostaria de continuar usando o @Html.EditorFor porque ela implementa um monte de outras coisas que são úteis. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Coloca um Html.EditorFor(p => p.DataNascimento, new { @value=@Model.DataNascimento.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") })

Comment: @pcmoraes posta aqui a linha para outras pessoas com o mesmo problema usar como referência.

Comment: Oi Diego, a última sugestão não funcionou. Consegui outra forma de fazer isso com DataAnnotations. Na classe pessoa, decoro a propriedade DataNascimento com [DataType(DataType.Date)] e [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]. Aí, posso usar o EditorFor normalmente que funciona. (ainda não consigo formatar meus comentários como você e não  sei como começar. Bom, mas isso é outro assunto).

Comment: Esta não é, ainda, a melhor forma de fazer isso, porque preciso fazer esta anotação em todos os campos do tipo DateTime das classes de domínio. Já encontrei soluções de código pra fazer isso customizando o Model Binder do MVC, mas não tô conseguindo fazer funcionar.

Comment: Sim, eu tinha visto a solução ontem, mas como não utilizo o @EditorFor fiquei meio sem opções, mas essa é a forma de fazer mesmo, está correto.

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

Busque o dado no banco, via SQL como você geralmente faz, neste exemplo colocado nesta variável:

```php
=> $dadosTrazidosDoBancoNestaArray['dataDoBanco']
```

E trate:

```php
$dataFormatada = trim($dadosTrazidosDoBancoNestaArray['dataDoBanco']);
$dataFormatada = date("**Y-m-d**", strtotime($dataFormatada));
```

Imprima no campo `type="date"` ou `type="text"` mesmo, mas no caso de `type="text"` altere a ordem de exibição do date para "**d-m-Y**" para ficar certinho.

```html
<input readonly type="date" name='data' value="<?php echo $dataFormatada ?>">
<input readonly type="text" name='data' value="<?php echo $dataFormatada ?>">
```

Repare que a sintaxe é praticamente a mesma, no entanto, ressalvo que não será exibido no campo date com a formatação em "**d-m-Y**", pois só reconhecerá a sintaxe "**Y-m-d**".

Answer (score 0):

A quem for ajudar utilizo da seguinte forma

```
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dia" id="dia" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($cli["dia"]));?>" />
```

Me retorna o valor gravado no banco